# ng-bing with symfony2 and translation

Tags: angularjs, symfony, translation

I wanna know, How can I put the next code in angularJS to apply the translation of symfony2:

```
<div ng-bind="message"></div>

$scope.message = '{{ 'backoffice.admin.user.labels.email_valid' | trans }}';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ajax to get that data, it is just nicer and cleaner solution for single page application.

But if you really want it, can use something like this:

```
<div data-ng-init="message = {{ 'backoffice.admin.user.labels.email_valid' | trans }}"></div>
```

But it is easier and better to do something like this:

```
$http.get('/url').
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.message = data;
  })
```

Also it is better to have message in object so instead $scope.message it would be $scope.someObject.message.

Comment: I need modify message value depend of my ajax